# TrixBox Samba share stopped working

Tags: samba, trixbox

I have a TrixBox VoIP server running TrixBox CE 2.6.2.3. Up until recently, I was able to access a Samba share on that box at \astersik\share from my Windows PCs. The share is suddenly no longer working, I get an error message "Windows cannot access \asterisk\share" and the error code is 0x80004005 "unspecified error". Really helpful, Windows, thanks.

I'm pretty clueless when it comes to Linux - can anyone help me troubleshoot and check if Samba is configured right on the TrixBox? I've already tried running the setup_samba script, which runs successfully.

UPDATE: I discovered that it is only some newly-upgraded Windows 7 machines that can no longer access the Samba share. My server (2003) can see it OK. Hmmm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the new authentication in Windows Vista / 7 that stops older versions of Samba from communicating.

I had the same problem on a NAS (as most off the shelf NASs are based on Samba)

It is advised to leave it set, but if you want to turn it off, do the following. (Assuming there is no Domain Policy and this is a isolated machine or a workgroup)

Go to Control Panel > Administration Tools > Local Security Policy

From here, select Local Policies. Depending on the exact settings of the Samba server, it can be a few things but the first one to try should be.

Network security : LAN Manager authentication level. Try nocking this down a step at a time until you can access the Samba service.

If this does not help, Take a look at the other Network policies that are to do with authentication, especially NTLM/NTLMv2

The reason I am not listing all of them is because I am not 100% sure. To answer your question, I had a look at the security options and I have seen that there are quite a few new options since Vista. I apply my setting through group policy and have not had to look here for a while. I can confirm though that by doing the setting I said above, I can access a Samba share that I would of had problems with before so I think it should work.